# how to Create and Use SnackBar for ReUse(Globally) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, global, reusability, code-reuse, snackbar

i want create `SnackBar` for reusable(globally)

i already created but its only for 1 page , i don't know how to create **reusable**.

**below code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnackBarMain extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnackBarMainState createState() => _SnackBarMainState();
}

class _SnackBarMainState extends State<SnackBarMain> {
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String title = 'SnackBar';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple)),
          onPressed: () => snackBarMsg(context),
          color: Colors.purple,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text("SnackBar",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

snackBarMsg(BuildContext context) {
    final sb = SnackBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      content: Text('SnackBar Bottom Message'),
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 5000000),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
      ),
      //backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      action: SnackBarAction(
        textColor: Color(0xFFFAF2FB),
        label: 'OK',
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
    globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(sb);
  }
}
```

so any one please give me example for this

Comment: Will that snackBar show same message all across the app ? you want that accessible globally.

Comment: no i want to show different message all across the app, and i want accessible globally

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just create a public class and put your custom functions inside, here you go for example:

```
//Custom class in project directory
class CustomWidgets {
 CustomWidgets._();
 static buildErrorSnackbar(BuildContext context, String message) {
  Scaffold.of(context)
     .showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text("$message"),
    ),
  );
 }
}

 // This is any page in your project

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      //        Always create body with Builder method so you can 
      //        get exact context to pass
      body: Builder(
      builder: (context) =>
          Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.pink,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){
                CustomWidgets.buildErrorSnackbar(context,"Your message here");
              },
              child: Text('Display SnackBar'),
          ),
         ),
     ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: you can add this code on view? I don't understand and add this correctly

Answer (score 20):

You can have a `class` that has a static method `show()` which receives the `context` and shows a `snackbar`. 
Check te code below.

```
class GlobalSnackBar {
  final String message;

  const GlobalSnackBar({
    @required this.message,
  });

  static show(
    BuildContext context,
    String message,
  ) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        content: Text(message),
        duration: new Duration(seconds: 5000000),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0), topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
        ),
        //backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        action: SnackBarAction(
          textColor: Color(0xFFFAF2FB),
          label: 'OK',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can call it from anywhere like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('SHOW Snackbar'),
      onPressed: () => GlobalSnackBar.show(context, 'Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

Remember that the `context` you pass to `show()` method has to be a descendant from `Scaffold` in order to show the `SnackBar`

Comment: yaaah buddy! very thanks, It was what I needed

Answer (score 3):

**Scaffold.of(context).showSnackbar** is deprecated now. You should use **ScaffoldMessenger** instead. Use like this:-

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('User Successfully Logged In...'),
        ));
```

Comment: You mean Scaffold.of(context).showSnackbar(snackbar)... is deprecated.

Comment: @ReinierGarcia Yes it is deprecated now .

Comment: You don't understand yet. What is deprecated is Scaffold.of(context).showSnackbar. NOT SnackBar.showSnackbar. You are literally saying: "SnackBar.showSnackbar is deprecated now..." and that is not correct.

Comment: @ReinierGarcia Yes you are true. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Snackbar` you have already defined to reuse it everywhere by putting it in a public folder, that can be accessed from anywhere in your app. You don't need to enclose it inside a widget or a class. Then, you can show it by calling `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(...)`. For that, you will need to pass the current `BuildContext`, of course. This way, as long as the `context` from which you call `showSnackBar` has a parent `Scaffold`, the snackbar will be shown for your current page, and you can do this from anywhere.

Consider this example, that I myself have used in the past:

```dart
  void buildErrorSnackbar(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text("Oops! Something went wrong."),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: bro how to call snackbar in another Page?

Comment: You can declare your own `buildSnackbar` method anywhere, you don't need to enclose it in a class. This way you can call if from anywhere, you just need to pass the corresponding `BuildContext`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a public snackbar class like this

```
//=========================================================
// PUBLIC SNACK BAR WIDGET
//=========================================================
class PublicSnackBar extends SnackBar {
  const PublicSnackBar({Key? key, required super.content}) : super(key: key);
}
```

and call it in any pages or files in the project, tho I am using public context here.

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(navigatorKey.currentContext as BuildContext)
        .showSnackBar(PublicSnackBar(content: Text('$result')));
```

this is my public context, just in case you were wondering,

```
//=========================================================================
// NAVIGATING WITH OUT CONTEXT
//=========================================================================
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Comment: this is 2021 and i find this very clean to use, if i am mistaken please do let me know

Comment: how to have default values in your PublicSnackBar class ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to build a Extension like that then your problem will be solve if you try to create a widget for that then you face some problems so try to use extension [Output will be look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjhui.png)

```
 extension SnackBarExt on BuildContext {
  void fluidSnackBar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(this)
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimension.d4),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimension.d1)),
          backgroundColor: secondarySwatch.shade800,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: Dimension.d3, horizontal: Dimension.d4),
          content: Text(message,
              style: fluidTextStyles.caption.colored(secondarySwatch.shade25),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)));
  }
```